# Building up a list of dictionaries from a few lists in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a few lists like this:

```
Pargs = [args.Pee, args.Pem,...,args.Pet] # 9 elements of boolean type
indices = [(0,0),(0,1),...,(2,2)] # 9 possible combinations (i,j), i = 0,1,2; j = 0,1,2
D = [{},{},...,{}] # 9 dictionaries, desired result
```

The result I want to see should look like this:

```
D = [{event:args.Pee,i:0,j:0},{event:args.Pem,i:0,j:1},...{event: args.Pet,i:2,j:2}]
```

The dictionaries must be ordered like shown above.

I tried

```
for d in D:
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            d['i'],d['j'] = i,j
```

but it does not do the trick. I've tried numerous algorithms with zip(),product(),dict(), but to no avail...

Comment: You're just combining `Pargs[0]` and `indices[0]`, `Pargs[1]` and `indices[1]`, etc?

Comment: @glibdud As far as I understand, yes.

Comment: Do the dicts have to be ordered?

Comment: I have edited that requirement into the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a comprehension and `OrderedDict`, demo:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
pargs = ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 'arg4', 'arg5', 'arg6', 'arg7', 'arg8', 'arg9']
indices = ((x,y) for x in range(3) for y in range(3))
result = [OrderedDict([('event',p), ('i',i), ('j',j)]) for p,(i,j) in zip(pargs, indices)]
print(result) # [OrderedDict([('event', 'arg1'), ('i', 0), ('j', 0)]), OrderedDict([('event', 'arg2'), ('i', 0), ('j', 1)]), OrderedDict([('event', 'arg3'), ('i', 0), ('j', 2)]), OrderedDict([('event', 'arg4'), ('i', 1), ('j', 0)]), OrderedDict([('event', 'arg5'), ('i', 1), ('j', 1)]), OrderedDict([('event', 'arg6'), ('i', 1), ('j', 2)]), OrderedDict([('event', 'arg7'), ('i', 2), ('j', 0)]), OrderedDict([('event', 'arg8'), ('i', 2), ('j', 1)]), OrderedDict([('event', 'arg9'), ('i', 2), ('j', 2)])]
```

*edit*

If I misunderstood your requirements and the order *within* the dictionaries does not matter, you can do it without an `OrderedDict` like this:

```
result = [{'event':p, 'i':i, 'j':j} for p,(i,j) in zip(pargs, indices)]
```

Comment: Oh it's okay. Wow great solution! It is neat and concise. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Albert no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of your question, you're looking to do something like the following:

```
>>> Pargs = [str(i) for i in range(9)]
>>> Pargs
9: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
>>> indeces = [(i, j) for i in range(3) for j in range(3)]
10: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
>>> D = [{'event':Pargs[ind], 'i':i[0], 'j':i[1]} for ind, i in enumerate(indeces)]
>>> D
11: [{'event': '0', 'i': 0, 'j': 0},
 {'event': '1', 'i': 0, 'j': 1},
 {'event': '2', 'i': 0, 'j': 2},
 {'event': '3', 'i': 1, 'j': 0},
 {'event': '4', 'i': 1, 'j': 1},
 {'event': '5', 'i': 1, 'j': 2},
 {'event': '6', 'i': 2, 'j': 0},
 {'event': '7', 'i': 2, 'j': 1},
 {'event': '8', 'i': 2, 'j': 2}]
>>>
```

The key you seemed to be missing in your attempts was to iterate through indeces and Pargs at the same time.

Comment: Yap! That's precisely what I need. I feel sad and happy at the same time. Happy cos I've finally got what I need and sad cos it's sad that I couldn't figure it out on my own. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Very welcome. Express your thanks in the form of delicious karma and accept my answer :)

Comment: I voted up your reply. But, in my judgement, it happes that the guy above came up with a more beautiful solution. Even though it's not too different from yours. It's really hard to choose the best answer here!

Comment: I agree with you actually and have also upvoted timgeb's answer :D

Answer (score 0):

You want just a single loop where you keep track of multiple indices. Maybe this isn't what you're looking for, but go from here

```
i = 0
j = 0
for d in range(9):
    D[d] = {'event':Pargs[d], 'i':i, 'j':j}
    if j == 2:
        j = 0
        i += 1
    else:
        j += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Pargs` and `indices` have the same number of elements, you can do it one of these two ways, depending on what you meant by "the dicts have to be ordered".

This will produce a list of dictionaries in the order shown in your question:

```
D = [{'event': parg, 'i':pair[0], 'j':pair[1]}
        for parg, pair in zip(Pargs, indices)]
```

If you meant you wanted the *contents* of each dictionary to be in the order shown (as well as their order in the list), you need to use a `collections.OrderedDict` to hold the data because regular dictionaries don't preserve the order of their contents (the key, value pairs).

```
from collections import OrderedDict

D = [OrderedDict([('event', parg), ('i', pair[0]), ('j', pair[1])])
        for parg, pair in zip(Pargs, indices)]
```